# HTML code to show current date & time in text box when i click on start button

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to show current date & time in text box when i click on start time same for end time.

Addition* post clicking on SUBMIT button my page is redirecting to PHP page which is saving my input to MYSQL.

code:

```
<head>
<title>Survey</title>
</head>

<body>
<Center><b><font size="10" color="White">SURVEY</font></Center></b>
</body>

<body background="logo.jpg"> 

<BR></BR>

<BR></BR>

<form action="action.php" method="post" />
<p><Center><font size="4" color="White">Employee ID: <input type="text" name="employee_id" /></font></Center></p>
<BR></BR>
<p><Center><font size="4" color="White">Unique ID: <input type="text" name="unique_id" /></font></Center></p>
<BR></BR>
<p><Center><font size="4" color="White">Category: <input type="text" name="category" /></font></Center></p>
<BR></BR>
<p><Center><button >Start Time</Button> <input type="text" name="start_time" /></Center></p>
<BR></BR>   
<p><Center><button >End Time</Button> <input type="text" name="end_time" /></Center></p>
<BR></BR>
<Center><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></Center>


</form>
```

Comment: Use JavaScript onClick event.

Comment: please include the code you have tried to make it happen... also, are you looking for a javascript implementation or need an interim page that will show the time...?

Answer (score 2):

You can use datapicker to do this for you as below

```
<label>Start Time </lable>
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" />
<label>End Time </lable>
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" />

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function () {
        $('#data').text(this.value);
    }
});
```

[Working JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsfpgdk/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Here do it with jquery 
http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/

And then the set time example. It sets the time on button click.

just add `id` to the input name it like i did ( `#start_time` )

```
$('#start_time').timepicker();
$('#setTimeButton').on('click', function (){
    $('#start_time').timepicker('setTime', new Date());
});
```

UPDATE

but what you were asking for was on button click so:
remove the buttons and add `input` with type `button` and `id` ('#start_time')

```
$('#start_time').click(function(){
    var dt = new Date();
    var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds() + "-" + dt.getDate() + "-" + dt.getMonth() + "-" + dt.getFullYear();
    $('#start_time_input').val(time);
});
```

do the same with the "end time"

NOTE: don't forget to add jquery in the header download it on 
jquery.com

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/o51gqk76/1/)